# Slow performance using local impersonation on ASP

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, windows-authentication

I'm working on a large web application running under IIS 6.0 and connecting to an SQL Server 2005 database. I'm currently trying to connect to the database using Windows Authentication to properly log which user account updates records in the database, but I've run into a bit of a performance issue; The initial connection that establishes the session takes easily over a minute to finish.

There are no network issues (This is a test server, so all tests are local). My IIS is configured to use Basic Authentication (I need the login info plain) and Local Impersonation is enabled, with an empty username/password setting.

This setup establishes the connection properly, but as mentioned, takes way too long to start up (subsequent queries are performed at normal speed)

Does anyone know if Local Impersonation should affect performance this dramatically? Am I looking in the wrong place? Is there any way to force SQL Server to keep the database connection open?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: add an entry in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts for your sql server. maybe it's the DNS or WINS.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way you reference your local server. If your application settings are (local)\instance_name update it to (127.0.0.1)\instance_name.

I’ve had similar performance issue in the past and this fixed it. Note that you’ll need to add this IP address as one of the listeners in SQL Server Configuration manager under Network configuration -> TCP/IP